# Port 16-bit assembly code to 32 bit

Tags: assembly

Yesterday i've found some old floppy-disks with some old windows 3.1-apps on it.

To get these to work on my 64-bit pc I disassembled them with IDA but I'm not sure how to compile these again to 32-bit?

Are there any steps to be done before compiling? Or can i just compile them?

Also, which assembly-compiler is best for these types of apps?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Use DOSBox.

Comment: To be sure, I want to compile them. I know i'm able with dosbox to get them running right away but I want to give some of them to my grandmother and I don't think she can work with dosbox.

Comment: The 16-bit API is not compatible with the 32-bit API at the assembly level, so a literal instruction-by-instruction port will get you nowhere. Calling conventions are different, the memory model is different, the module format is different...

Comment: @JeroenDeMeerleer You can automate the DOSBox process with a batch file, so that she doesn't have not worry about it.

Comment: You can pack everything inside an EXE including DOSBox and the programs. What you definitely can't do is recompile a 16-bit binary to 32-bit.

Comment: Why not use virtualization software like VirtualBox? It's easy to use once you set it up. Assuming you have access to Windows 3.1 (or DOS ?) install cd.